# Set content schedule of content programmatically in Umbraco 11

Tags: .net-core, umbraco, schedule

I am trying to set the content schedule of a content in Umbraco 11 but I just can't get it to work. I can't find any reference relevant to Umbraco 11.

This is my code so far.

```
ContentSchedule sched = new ContentSchedule(doc.Key, "", expirationDate, ContentScheduleAction.Expire);

var contentScheduleCollection = new ContentScheduleCollection();
contentScheduleCollection.Add(sched);

contentService.Save(doc, contentSchedule: contentScheduleCollection);
```

This code runs with no errors but the schedule is not reflecting on the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who has encountered this, the solution is to not initialize ContentSchedule with the doc.key

Here's the working code.

```
ContentSchedule sched = new ContentSchedule("", expirationDate, ContentScheduleAction.Expire);

var contentScheduleCollection = new ContentScheduleCollection();
contentScheduleCollection.Add(sched);

contentService.Save(doc, contentSchedule: contentScheduleCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure something out?

I found [this mention](https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cms/fundamentals/setup/upgrading/version-specific#umbraco-10), saying that you can also do

```
contentService.PersistContentSchedule(doc, contentScheduleCollection);
```

Source code for both [the latest](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/contrib/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/IContentService.cs#L100)  version [and version 11](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/v11/dev/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/IContentService.cs#L100) suggests that the method exists and should at least [do **something**](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/contrib/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/ContentService.cs#L514) ...